# How do you send messages between different users of the same app?

Tags: android, ios, message

I want to make a in app message system that only shows in the app like tinder but to use the app the person doesn't have to login using anything. I was wonder how will someone be able to do that and if it is possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but needs extra effort from you. Sorry it's hardly possible to provide fully detailed answer in a post, so briefly:

1) To pass messages between instances of your app you need server. I use Google [AppEngine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine) with [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs) for similar task (it's free while you are in certain [limits](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas))

2) To avoid logging-in you may use Google account that user entered while configuring device. 
 To get account on device you may use this code:

```
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context/*activity*/);
    Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    for (Account acc : accounts) {
        userEmail = acc.name.trim();
    // do whatever you need with account
    }
```